# VCD error in RISCV (RocketChip) emulator

Tags: riscv, chisel

I am facing problem related to rocketchip emulator. I have generated the debugged emulator. I was trying to get vcd waveform so i run following command. i got vcd file with a error message:

```
 ./emulator-freechips.rocketchip.system-DefaultConfig-debug -v test_simple.vcd -c $RISCV/riscv64-unknown-elf/share/riscv-tests/isa/rv64ui-p-simple
    This emulator compiled with JTAG Remote Bitbang client. To enable, use +jtag_rbb_enable=1.
Listening on port 32973
*** FAILED *** (code = 714077000, seed 1518193369) after 35908 cycles
```

Is this a right way to get vcd. ? why I am getting the error 
thanks

Comment: probably jtag has an issue. what if I manually disable?